# Sending an image from .Net server to Android client using sockets

Tags: android, .net, image, sockets

Working on a project where an Android client communicates with a .Net server via sockets.
It can pass text messages without issue.
It now needs to be expanded to pass an jpeg image.

The server side code:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open)
Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
sendBytes = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
logger.Debug("sending " & sendBytes.Length & " bytes")
clientStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
clientStream.Flush()
clientStream.Close()
```

The Android client code:

message send / receive

```
socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

byte[] outputBytes = requestString.getBytes();
writer.write(outputBytes);
Log.d(method, "Message sent: " + requestString);
while ((responseString = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    response += responseString + "\n";
}
reader.close();
writer.close();
socket.close();
```

then trying to reconstruct the image from the response:

```
byte[] imageBytes = reponse.getBytes();
Log.d(method, "imageBytes.length: " + imageBytes.length);
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
ImageView imageV = new ImageView(activity);
imageV.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
```

LogCat error message is: SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

PLUS the server log says it sent 14548 bytes,
BUT the client log says it received 25294 bytes.

An encoding issue?
I tried adding encoding to the server BinaryReader, no luck.

I also tried on the client side:

```
imageV.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length));
```

I have spent hours looking through dozens of posts, I also tried other changes I can't even remember.
but, always "Factory returned null"

What am I doing wrong?

Edit----
Tried changing to

```
byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decode(response, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

That generated: IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use readLine() to read the bytes of an image.

Declare a buffer and in a loop read() bytes in the buffer and save them.

You cannot use intermediate Strings either.

If the server only sends an image you could even use

```
imageV.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(socket.getInputStream()));)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will give that a go.

Comment: That switch made the difference!
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

variable of position in inputstream may be set to 1024 after the first decode. So add inputstream.reset() before the second decode. Hope that works.

Comment: Not sure I follow, but I tried inserting the line 

    is.reset()
 
just before ImageView creation.
Got the same exact result.